# Excel: How to move data across from one column to another column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have one problem. I need to move data across from one column to another column in alternative rows in MS-Excel.

To make it easier please see **screenshot**. It shows the exact output I need.

If possible please provide the solution through **formula** rather than VBA code.

Many thanks in advance for your kind support.

Regards
James

[How to move cell across in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56uEp.png)

Answer (score 4):

### ROW Dependent Formulas

For the setup in the screenshot use the following formulas:

```
[G2] =IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,C3,"")
[H2] =IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,C2,"")
```

Here's a VBA solution if you really want to rearrange (move) the data in place:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveData()

    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"     ' Worksheet Name
    Const srcRange As String = "C2:C11"   ' Source Range Address
    Const tgtRange As String = "B2:C11"   ' Target Range Address

    Dim ws As Worksheet     ' Worksheet
    Dim Source As Variant   ' Source Array
    Dim Target As Variant   ' Target Array
    Dim i As Long           ' Source/Target Array Element (Row) Counter

    ' Define worksheet.
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
    ' Copy Source Range to Source Array.
    Source = ws.Range(srcRange)

    ' Copy values from Source Array to Target Array.
    ReDim Target(1 To UBound(Source), 1 To 2)
    For i = 1 To UBound(Target) Step 2
        Target(i, 1) = Source(i + 1, 1)
        Target(i, 2) = Source(i, 1)
    Next i

    '-Copy values from Target Array to Target Range.
    ws.Range(tgtRange) = Target

End Sub
```

Comment: VBasic2008, you are fantastic. You made my day. It's so helpful. Many thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Nice coding style *(+1)*

Comment: VBasic2008, you just rocks! I appreciate your proactiveness. It's even better solution. I have tested and it works like charm!  However, when I run against large data it's giving me error. "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range".  My programmatic skill is poor. I assume I need to make some minor change. Not sure anything you suggest? I am testing having 500 rows under "B" column. Once again thank you for your kind help. (I assume it's possible to add screenshots in the comment i.e. here)

Comment: @James: An error should occur when there is an `odd` number of data. The code was written for data pairs (`even` number (`Step 2`)), so just select one cell (row) more or less, e.g. use `C2:C501` instead of `C2:C500`.

Comment: Thank you very much again. It works like charm. No error data copied. but it didn't move. Is something you suggest? Code I am using " Const wsName As String = "Sheet3"     
    Const srcRange As String = "B2:B111"   
    Const tgtRange As String = "A2:A111"

Comment: Just to mention. It worked as I expected. The only thing it copied not moved. Now it's not a problem for me as I can easily get rid of that unwanted row. It's just one manual step. So if there is no solution I am happy to live with it. Thanks again.

Comment: @James: You should use `Const tgtRange As String = "A2:B111"`. You did have a serial number in column `A`. So you got rid of it?

Comment: Perfect! It works. Thank you very much. I appreciate it. Thanks again.